# Twilio Inbound SMS issue using Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am trying to set up a node.js app as listener for twilio inbound sms.I have created a twilio account which gave me trial sandbox number(USA).

Using this trial number I was able to successfully send SMS to verified mobile numbers But when I send SMS to the sandbox trial number my app is not able to receive the same and twilio logs also didn't show up the inbound SMS details.
I have configured the end point in twilio SMS URL and the end point is accessible.
Are there any restrictions for inbound SMLS for twilio trial sandbox number. I have sent multiple messages to the number but still no luck.

Please note am trying to send SMS to a US twilio sandbox number from India. Could you suggest what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here,

I apologize for this issue you are running into. I have just recreated this issue, as did another member of my team. A bug report has been filed.

Keep in mind, you can still obtain a unique Twilio number while using a trial account. See the [Getting Started](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/voice-sms-mms/getting-started?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon) page to get your Twilio number. This will allow you to use our API while still being on a trial account. The limitations of trial accounts [can be found here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-does-twilios-free-trial-work?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon).

Thanks for bringing this to our attention, we'd love to mail you a Twilio t-shirt to say thank you.  Since Stack Overflow doesn't allow for private messaging, please shoot me a private message on twitter to [@br0dan](https://twitter.com/br0dan) with your address and t-shirt size.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brodan..Have configured as you suggested.It worked.